# Calculating the joint distribution of two random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

Consider three independent random variables X, Y, and Z. Here, X and Y are i.i.d exponential random variables with parameter λ, and Z is an exponential random variable with parameter μ. Let's consider two random variables, R=X−Z and S=Y−Z. How can I find the joint distribution of $S$ and $R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea to approach such problems is the following :
Take $h$ an arbitrary function.

If you can show that
$E(h(R,S)) = \int \int f(r,s)dr ds$, then you have found $f$ the joint pdf of $R,S$.

So let's go.

$E(h(R,S)) = E(h(X-Z,Y-Z)) = \int \int \int 1_{x>0} 1_{y>0} 1_{z>0} h(x-z,y-z)e^{-\lambda x} e^{-\lambda y} e^{-\lambda z} dxdydz$.

Now you want to change your 3 variables $x,y,z$ to three other ones. Obviously you have to do $r=x-z$ and $s=y-z$. The third one is your choice, but the obvious choice here is $z' = z$. The jacobian of this change of variables is obviously $1$. Hence

$E(h(R,S)) = E(h(X-Z,Y-Z)) = \int \int \int 1_{r+z'>0} 1_{s+z'>0} 1_{z'>0}h(r,s)\lambda e^{-\lambda (r+z')} \lambda e^{-\lambda (s+z')} \lambda  e^{-\lambda z'} drdsdz'$.

Note : we rewrote the bounds of the integrals as indicators. Useful trick in multivariate change of variables.

Now you want to integrate out $z'$. First bring out everything that doesn't involve it.

$= \int \int h(r,s) \lambda^3 e^{-\lambda (r+s)}\left(\int 1_{z'>-r} 1_{z'>-s} 1_{z'>0}e^{-3\lambda z'} dz'\right) drds$.

So the inner integral is

$\int 1_{z'>-\min(0,r,s)}e^{-3\lambda z'} dz' = \dfrac{e^{3\lambda\min(0,r,s)}}{3\lambda}$.

Hence

$E(h(R,S)) = \int \int h(r,s) \lambda^3 e^{-\lambda (r+s)}\dfrac{e^{3\lambda\min(0,r,s)}}{3\lambda} drds = \int \int h(r,s)\frac{\lambda^2}{3} e^{\lambda(3\min(0,r,s) - r - s)} dr ds$

Hence $\frac{\lambda^2}{3} e^{\lambda(3\min(0,r,s) - r - s)}$ is your joint pdf.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer. If we consider the conditions $X>Z$ and $Y>Z$, is this joint distribution true?

Comment: Indeed, I want to know whether $R$ and $S$ are independent or not?

Comment: Intuitively, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $Z$ is common between them, therefore, $S$ and $R$ can be independent.

Comment: I don't know if this is true or not.

Comment: What I just computed is the unconditional distribution. If you want the distribution conditional on $Y,X>Z$, then this is another computation : $E(h(X,Y)1_{Y,X>Z}/P(Y,X>Z))$.

Comment: Can we say that the $R$ and $S$ are independent in the conditional case?

Comment: So you need to update your question if you want the conditional probability distribution. In that case it will turn out that $X,Y$ are independent exponentials. You can also prove that through soft arguments using the memoryless property of the exponential distrib. The reasoning you give for X being independent of Y is wrong, because that's not the case in general, just a byproduct  of the niceness of exponential distributions in your example.

Comment: I am sorry for too many questions; in what situation is my reasoning valid?

Comment: For example, if $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent random variables based on different general distributions, what kinds of conditions are needed so that my reasoning would be valid.

Comment: It's never valid unless you add another justification to it. R and S are a priori dependent on Z so their is a common factor that influences them both. You must also say that conditional on $X>Z$, R is independent of Z. The same will apply to R. And that's only because X is exponentially distributed hence has the memoryless property.

Comment: I am sorry, this is my last question; how $R$ can be independent of $Z$ while $R=X-Z$? Just in the case of exponential distribution and memoryless property?

Comment: What you just said is true **conditional on X>Z**. That's when X is independnet of Z and X is exponentially distributed.